# SQL query to split columns to multiple columns

Tags: sql, oracle

```
product      cost
-----------------
X             50
Y            100
Z            110
X            250
Y             50
X            500
```

Desired output:

```
p1  c1  p2  c2
----------------
x   50  x   250
y   100 y    50
z   110 null null
```

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of answer you expect to receive from this question if you can't be bothered to actually ask a question... What do you have and what do you want to have? What does `O/p` mean?

Comment: I suspect O/p means "expected output". The title mentions columns but the way the text is formatted, who knows how many columns there are and what is in each column? I'm not even going to try on this one.

Comment: Please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

Use a `PIVOT` on the `ROW_NUMBER` for each `product`:

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( product, cost ) AS
  SELECT 'X',   50 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Y',  100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Z',  110 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'X',  250 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Y',   50 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'X',  500 FROM DUAL
```

**Query**:

```sql
SELECT product AS p1,
       c1,
       product AS p2,
       c2
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY product ORDER BY ROWNUM ) AS rn
  FROM   table_name t
)
PIVOT ( MAX( cost ) FOR rn IN ( 1 AS c1, 2 AS c2 ) )
```

**Output**:

> ```
> P1 |  C1 | P2 |   C2
> :- | --: | :- | ---:
> X  |  50 | X  |  250
> Y  | 100 | Y  |   50
> Z  | 110 | Z  | null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4e45e18dfcc3e423319b8dd6a59dbae7)*